# I am learning django, how to change function to class in the views.py

Tags: django

How to change function to class in the views.py

I want to change the view to something like this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

```
class NewTopic(CreateView):
    model = Topic
    fields = ['title', 'category', 'author', 'text']
    template_name = 'app_a/new_category.html'
```

This is not correct, i want to modify it.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=localtime)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def new_topic(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.author = request.user
            new_topic.category = category
            new_topic.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:category', args=[pk]))
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/index.html')

    context = {'category': category, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/new_topic.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['title', 'author']


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5,'cols': 50}))
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'author', 'text']
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^new_topic/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
]
```

I don't know how to modify it, thank you!

Comment: Do you really need it or do you want to learn about how to use Class based view? If letter, than I suggest you experiment with with CBV and clues to modification are to override `form_valid` and `get_success_url` methods

Comment: What is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have your forms, try doing the following:

```
class NewTopic(CreateView):
    model = Topic
    form_class = TopicForm
    template_name = 'app_a/new_category.html'
```

Also, in your `urls,py`, you need to specify the new class based view.

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^new_topic/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.NewTopic.as_view(), name='new_topic'),
]
```

You can override the `form_valid` method to add your custom logic.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # your logic
```